# Apache ProxyPass to custom port

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, virtualhost, reverse-proxy

The problem is following: I have an `index.html` file that is located under `/www/site/` and I want to be able to serve all appropriate content from that folder under custom port lets say `:8085`. It is also only accessible through `ProxyPass`. Configurations look like this:

`site.dev` in `/available-sites` folder:

```
Listen 8085

<VirtualHost *:8085>
    DocumentRoot "/www/site"
    ServerName site.dev
    ServerAlias site.dev

    <Directory "/www/site">
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And the `httpd.conf` looks like this:

```
ProxyPass /site http://localhost:8085/site
ProxyPassReverse /site http://localhost:8085/site
```

After setting this kind of configuration the server is not responding and `error.log` file is filled with:

```
proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (site.dev)
ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (site.dev)
caught SIGTERM, shutting down
server reached MaxClients settings ....
```

I am running Ubuntu with latest Apache2. Any ideas how this kind of configuration could work?